# Flash Player in a Webbrowser in a WinForm takes too much memory

Tags: .net-4.0, memory-leaks, flash

I'm embedding a Flash Player in a webpage which is shown in a `Webbrowser` on a `Form`. After several minutes, memory usage grows up abnormally. Calling `Dispose()` on the `Form` and then `GC.Collect()` doesn't fix that issue.

Can I tell Flash Player's ActiveX to free memory, or unload myself Flash Player's ActiveX from memory?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the WebBrowser control. Perhaps you should consider submitting a bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: By the way, has the fact of disposing a Webbrowser the same effect as to close an Internet Explorer window?

Answer (score 0):

After having played some Flash videos in Internet Explorer, it appear that it's due to Flash Player itself.